# Integrating an even function (mod 1) against $t^{-3/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $g:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable and satisfy $g(-t)=g(t)$. Let $t_1\geq t_0>0$. Then I can show that
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{g(t)}{t^{3/2}} dt&= 2 g_0\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t_0}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{t_1}}\right)+ O^*\left(\frac{|g-g_0|_1+ \frac{1}{2} |g-g_0|_\infty}{t_0^{3/2}}\right), \end{aligned}$$
where $g_0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}} g(t) dt$.

The proof is neither difficult nor very long - I include it below the cut. At the same time, I feel that there has to be a substantially shorter proof -- more direct and with less casework. Is that the case?

---

By the Taylor expansion (first-order, with remainder) of $t\mapsto 1/t^{3/2}$ around a point $n+1/2$, we know that, for $n\leq t\leq n+1$, $$\frac{1}{t^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{3/2}}+ 
\left(\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\right)'\bigg|_{t=t_0}\cdot (t-(n+1/2))
$$ for some $t_0$ between $t$ and $n+1/2$. Since $(1/t^{3/2})'$ is increasing, it follows that $$\frac{1}{t^{3/2}} \leq \frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{3/2}}+ 
\left(\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\right)'\cdot (t-(n+1/2))=
\frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{3/2}}-\frac{3/2}{t^{5/2}} (t-(n+1/2)),
$$ Let $0\leq u<1$ and $t=n+u$.
Then, for $g(u)\geq g_0,$
$$\frac{g(u)}{t^{3/2}}\leq g(u) \left(\frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{3/2}}-\frac{3/2}{t^{5/2}} (t-(n+1/2))\right).$$ whereas, if $g(u)< g_0$, the convexity of $1/t^{3/2}$ and the condition $g(u)=g(-u)$ give us
$$\frac{g(u)}{(n+u)^{3/2}} + \frac{g(-u)}{(n+1-u)^{3/2}}
= g(u) \left(\frac{1}{(n+u)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(n+1-u)^{3/2}}\right)
\leq \frac{2 g(u)}{(n+1/2)^{3/2}}.$$
Hence $$\begin{aligned}\int_n^{n+1} \frac{g(t)}{t^{3/2}} dt &= g_0 \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}} + \int_n^{n+1} \frac{g(t)-g_0}{t^{3/2}} dt\\&\leq
g_0 \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{3/2}}\int_n^{n+1} (g(t)-g_0) dt +\frac{3}{2}\int_n^{n+1} \frac{n+1/2-t}{t^{5/2}} \max(g(t)-g_0,0) dt\\
&\leq g_0 \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}} + \frac{|g-g_0|_\infty}{2} O^*\left(\int_n^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\right)' dt\right).\end{aligned}$$ Since $\int_I (g(t)-g_0) dt \leq |g-g_0|_1/2$ for any interval $I\subset [0,1]$, we conclude that $$\begin{aligned}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{g(t)}{t^{3/2}} dt&= g_0 \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}} + O\left(\frac{|g-g_0|_1}{2 t_0^{3/2}} + \frac{|g-g_0|_1/2}{\max(t_0,\lfloor t_1\rfloor)^{3/2}}\right)+\frac{|g-g_0|_\infty}{2} O^*\left(\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \left(\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\right)' dt\right)\\&= \frac{2 g_0}{\sqrt{t_0}} + O^*\left(\frac{|g-g_0|_1+ \frac{1}{2} |g-g_0|_\infty}{t_0^{3/2}}\right). \end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that establishes a slightly stronger and cleaner result. Of course giving a *shorter* proof would be at least as important important.

**Lemma.** Let $g:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable, with  $g(-t)=g(t)$. Let $1<\alpha\leq 3$ and $x_1\geq x_0\geq 1$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{g(x)}{x^{\alpha}} dx&= g_0\cdot \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}}+ O^*\left(\frac{|g-g_0|_1}{2 x_0^{\alpha}}\right), \end{aligned}$$
where $g_0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}} g(t) dt$.

*Proof.* Assume without loss of generality that $g_0=0$.  Write $f(x) = x^{-\alpha}$. Let us first estimate $\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} f(x) g(x) dx$ for $n$ an integer or half-integer with $n-1/2\geq 1$. Note that $g(n+t)=g(n-t)$. By a Taylor expansion with integral remainder term, $$ f(n+t) = f(n) + t f'(n) +\int_0^t (t-u) f''(n+u) du.$$
Since $f(n) \int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} g(x) dx = g_0 f(n)=0$ and $f'(n) \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} g(n+t) t dt = 0$,
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} f(x) g(x) dx&=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} g(n+t) \int_0^t (t-u) f''(n+u) du\\ &=\int_{0}^{1/2} g(n+t) \int_0^t (t-u) (f''(n+u) +f''(n-u)) du\end{aligned}$$
Since $f$ is convex-up, $$\int_0^t (t-u) (f''(n+u) +f''(n-u)) du\leq \frac{t}{2} \int_0^t (f''(n+u) +f''(n-u)) du.$$ In general, since $g_0=0$ and $g(t)=g(-t)$,  $\int_0^{1/2} g(t) h(t)\leq H \int_0^{1/2} \max(g(t),0) \leq \frac{H}{4} |g|_1$ for $h$ non-negative, where $H=\sup h$, and, similarly, $\int_0^{1/2} g(t) h(t)\geq -\frac{H}{4} |g|_1$. We conclude that $$\begin{aligned}\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} f(x) g(x) dx
&= O^*\left(\frac{|g|_1}{16} \max_{t\leq 1/2} \int_0^{t} (f''(n+u) +f''(n-u)) du \right)\\&=
\frac{|g|_1}{16} \left(\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} f''(x) dx \right).\end{aligned}$$ In the same way, $\int_{n-u}^{n+u} f(x) g(x) dx = \frac{|g|_1}{16} O^*\left(\int_{n-t}^{n+t} f''(x) dx \right)$ for any $t\leq 1/2$. We also obtain the easy bound $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(t) g(t) dt = f(t_0)\cdot O^*\left( \frac{|g|_1}{4}\right)$ for any interval $[t_0,t_1]$ contained in $[n,n+1/2]$ for $n$ a half-integer.

Note that $f''(x)=\alpha (\alpha+1)/x^{\alpha+1} \leq - 4 f'(x)$ for $x\geq 1\geq (\alpha+1)/4$. Hence, for any interval $I=[m,x_1]$ with $m\in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}$, $m\geq 1$ and $\{x_1-m\}\leq 1/2$, $$\int_I f(x) g(x) dx = \frac{|g|_1}{4} O^*\left(-\int_m^{m_1} f'(x) dx + f(m_1) \right)=\frac{|g|_1}{4} O^*(f(m_1)),$$ where $m_1=x_1-\{x_1-m\}$. Similarly, for any $I'=[x_0,m]$ with $m\in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}$, $x_0\geq 1$ and $m-x_0\leq 1$, we obtain $\int_{I'} f(x) g(x) dx = \frac{|g|_1}{4} O^*\left(f(x_0)\right)$ -- immediately if $m-x_0\leq 1/2$, or by $$\int_{I'} f(x) g(x) dx = \frac{|g|_1}{4} O^*\left(-\int_{m-1/2-r}^{m-1/2+r} f'(x) dx+f(m-1/2+r)\right) = \frac{|g|_1}{4} O^*(f(x_0))$$ with  $r=m_0-x_0-1/2$, if $m_0-x_0>1/2$.  It is easy to subdivide $[x_0,x_1]$ into two such intervals $I'$, $I$, and so we are done.

Comment: Do you really mean to take $x_0 \geq 1$ here?

Comment: Yes - what is the objection?

Comment: In the question the condition is $>0$ and here it is $\geq 1$, which seems more restrictive, so I don't see why the result is stronger.

Comment: Ok, sure, it's not technically stronger. I suppose I could try to remove that condution, even though it comes for free in my application.

Comment: OK - it's clear that one can remove it, at the cost of making the error term $|g-g_0|_1/x_0^{3/2}$ rather than $(1/2) |g-g_0|_1/x_0^{3/2}$. That's still better than the previous bound. Perhaps one can go further.